# Moving parameters from Excel Sheet to Excel Macro or SAS add-in

Tags: vba, excel, sas

I am trying to take values from an Excel sheet in order to update a SAS program. My code goes like this:

```
ods excel;
data _null_;


%LET SS1 = '15MAY2018'd;
%LET SS2 = '05JUN2018'd;

proc sql;
create table SAS3 as
select A.PHRHIST_PAYNO
from UVICRPT.V_HRS_PAYROLL_PHRHIST A, UVICRPT.V_HRS_PAYROLL_PHRDEDN B
WHERE
AND A.PHRHIST_ACTIVITY_DATE BETWEEN &SS1 AND &SS2
AND B.PHRDEDN_ACTIVITY_DATE BETWEEN &SS1 AND &SS2
AND A.PHRHIST_PICT_CODE = B.PHRDEDN_PICT_CODE
AND A.PHRHIST_YEAR = B.PHRDEDN_YEAR
AND A.PHRHIST_SEQ_NO = B.PHRDEDN_SEQ_NO;
run;


proc print data=SAS3 style=Table noobs;
run;
ods excel close;

QUIT;
```

I would like the variables SS1 and SS2 to take values from cells in my worksheet. Something like:

```
%LET SS1 = C5
```

Any ideas? I'm using the Add-in in Excel, SAS 7.15

Answer (score 1):

Use can use the XLSX engine to read and write Excel files directly, without going through an API. For example:

```
libname myworkbook xlsx "c:\sasdata\test.xlsx";
data test1;
set myworkbook.'Sheet1$C5:C5'n;
run;
libname myworkbook clear;
```